# breaking out of my infinite loop

Tags: c#

I have two buttons one for start and one for stop in my UI form,and i have one infinite loop that executes some function in my class name programs in a method.The start button is clicked by the user it invokes this method to execute the infinite loop and i need to break this infinite loop when the user clicks the stop button,after that my compiler will break out of this infinite loop and enters to the code inside the button stop click. 
I am trying to use the `Application.DoEvents()` method,this is working well if my infinite loop code is inside of the start button click,but if my infinite loop code is in the new class which is created by me i.e programs,how can use the `Application.DoEvents()` method to break out of this infinite loop.

Example:

```
namespace inFiniteLoopTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool stopBtnClk = false;
        bool startBtnClk = false;

        private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopBtnClk=false;

            startBtnClk = true;

            while(true)
            {
                //some code to be executed
                Application.DoEvents();
                if (stopBtnClk == true)
                {
                   break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void StopBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopBtnClk = true;
            if (startBtnClk == true)
            {
                //Application.Exit();
                MessageBox.Show("success");

            }

        }
```

this is working well.

But

```
public class programs
{    
    public static void infiniteLoop(bool stopBtnClick)
    {    
        while(true)
        {
            //some code to be executed
            Application.DoEvents();
            if (stopBtnClk == true)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }    
} 

//and my UI code to call this class is
namespace inFiniteLoopTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        bool stopBtnClk = false;
        bool startBtnClk = false;

        private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopBtnClk=false;    
            startBtnClk = true;
            programs.infiniteLoop(stopBtnClk);
        }

        private void StopBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopBtnClk = true;
            if (startBtnClk == true)
            {
                //Application.Exit();
                MessageBox.Show("success");
            }
        }            
    }
```

but this is not working .

Even if the compiler displays the message "success" when the stop button is clicked, but the debugger still said running in my form.
I hope my question is clear.
And i am kindly requesting you to answer my question as soon as possible and get rid of this problem!
I openly accept your answer if you come especially with a thread.

sorry i am a beginner for C#, but i need to continue on that.

Thank you!!

Comment: Why do you tag this question as `[java]`, `[php]`, `[c++]` and `[c]` if this question only pertains to C#? (I have edited it to include only the proper tags).

Comment: Please re-format the code. Select the whole block, and use the "code sample" feature on it, might have to do it twice, you will also see a preview of how it would finally look like.

Comment: You should use a thread to do the work.

Comment: Are you sure that the 2nd compiles? You accessing stopBtnClk inside programs.infiniteLoop. stopBtnClk is not a parameter nor a field of the class programs.

Comment: @ MrFox that is what i want,then help me on that to get rid of that problem using thread.10q

Comment: @ jfs try it but it is running even the stop button is clicked but the form is canceled reson to work is due  to the Application.DoEvent method

Answer (score 7):

Don't block the GUI thread. The fact that you have to use Application.DoEvents() to update the GUI is an indicator for bad design. Do the work in a separate worker thread.

[`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is predestinated for such a task.

Comment: There do not exist enough up arrows for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change signature of your infiniteLoop method like this:

`public static void infiniteLoop(ref bool stopBtnClick) 
...`

Comment: What about the method inside the start button click that is programs.infiniteLoop(stopBtnClk); to call this function.
Error Argument '1' must be passed with the 'ref' keyword

Comment: Pass it with ref like this:
programs.infiniteLoop(ref stopBtnClk);

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided is really difficult to read but as far as I can see when you create your infinite loop do:`while(looping) // do stuff`

Then when you press the Stop button set the bool variable looping to false and it will break out of the loop and show the message.

Comment: Once the compiler gets the infinite loop by the start button it doesn't go out of that loop,it doesn't consider for the actions/events (the stop button click) after you click it.That is my problem,and i need the trick to handle that event when the button is clicked.especially using thread.

Answer (score 0):

Why instead of an infinite loop you use a start stop condition determined by the buttons?

I thinking you can have a variable, just call it

```
bool stop_loop = false
```

and your loop

```
while(!stop_loop){ //CODE HERE }
```

Now when you click the first button (Start) you call the method (wherever it is) to start the loop. The loop is going to seem endless until you click the button stop and the value of stop_loop become in True.

HTH

Comment: @ SubniC: even if i made it it doesn't consider for the event of the stop button click

Comment: @subnic I think you need to add volatile to your bool declaration.

Comment: @Johnathan Brown Why not to use the volatile keyword? it will have some impact in the performance but is this a sufficient reason to never use it? Also it's used in an [example in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.90).aspx) which is similar to our case.

Comment: @وليدتاجالدين If you know EXACTLY what it does and you're 100% sure you want to use it in in multiple threads, then go ahead (Maybe I worded myself incorrectly). But, in this case you don't need to. Make a delegate and allow the thread to know off the variable, rather then throwing the volatile keyword around so all threads have access to it. I would recommend reading this article: http://theburningmonk.com/2010/03/threading-understanding-the-volatile-modifier-in-csharp/ The MSDN definition of volatile is very, misleading...

Comment: @Johnathan Brown Thank you for the very good article. According to the article - and to what I know about volatile - it may give a wrong feeling of safety, but there are some cases as you mentioned - when one actually know what he is doing - when it's safe to use the volatile keyword. Our case - using the variable only to terminate the thread - is safe as I think, and also it's the example mentioned in the article you provided for me to illustrate a situation in which volatile is safe.

Answer (score 0):

In the second code snippet, the infinite loop is started in a subroutine that accepts a boolean value as a parameter. How does that subroutine ever get a second chance to take a look at that boolean? It only "sees" the value once, and it's false at that time. It's a scoping question.

Comment: i think it is do to the event handler method   Application.DoEvents();
but is may wrong but it goes to the message "success" if i click the stop button but the reason behind is my form indicates me still running.but what is the difference between start debugging and start with out debugging, i confuse by these words also.